# C Passing an array of structures, array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c

I am writing a small web router. I wanted to write a generic function called `findRoute` that would accept a string as the route name and an array of structures to search through.

**router.c**

```
struct route 
{
   char *routeName;
   int routeId;
};
int findRoute(char find[], struct route list[])
{
   // do some strcmp 
   // return id of found route
}
```

It would be used like this

**subRouter.c**

```
enum someRoutes
{
  Route1,
  Route2
};
struct route someRoute[] = {
   {"route1", Route1},
   {"route2", Route2}
}
int routeId = findRoute("route1", someRoute);
switch(routeId){
   //etc
}
```

I am getting the error
`array type has incomplete element type` but only in my H file which simply looks like

**router.h**

```
int findRoute(char find[], struct route list[]);
```

My guess was I am not giving a size to the `list` parameter, but it doesn't seem to matter when I do.

Comment: That struct definition belongs in a header pulled in via-`#include` to *both* source files. Move it above the function decl in `router.h` and include it in *both* .c files.

Comment: what do you mean you get the error in the h file? header files aren't supposed to be compiled.

Comment: My only issue was not including the `struct` in the header.

Comment: @BarryBones41 - Just curious, if the value of a struct member in one .c file changes, does that value need to be seen and used in the other .c file?  If so, you should create an instance of the struct with `extern` scope in the header file, `#include` in both sources, initialize it in one source file.  Then you have a globally visible struct instance that allows each source file to have read and write access to members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the struct route definition from `router.c` to the header:

router.h:

```
struct route 
{
   char *routeName;
   int routeId;
};
```

And include `router.h` in `subRouter.c`.